# R combine 3 dataframes and perform operations

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, data.table

I have 3 dataframes which have different row numbers. I want to perform some operation on 2 dataframes based on row values in third dataframe.
dataframe 1:

```
+--------------------------+
| V1   Particlei Particlej |
+--------------------------+
| <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>    |
| 1 conf10   6   1829      |
| 2 conf10   6   13928     |
| 3 conf10   8   2875      |
| 4 conf10   8   13765     |
| 5 conf10   9   3184      |
| 6 conf10   9   11139     |
+--------------------------+
```

dataframe 2

```
+----------+----------+------------+-------------+
|    V1    |  cluster | position.x |  position.y |
+----------+----------+------------+-------------+
| <chr>    | <dbl>    |   <dbl>    |   <dbl>     |
| 1 conf10 | 6        | 0.000659   | 0.00932     |
| 2 conf10 | 8        | 0.0291     |  0.00922    |
| 3 conf10 | 10       | 0.0101     |   0.00380   |
| 4 conf10 | 12       | -0.0103    |  0.00379    |
| 5 conf10 | 14       |  0.0165    |  0.000900   |
| 6 conf10 | 16       | -0.000554  |   0.0112    |
+----------+----------+------------+-------------+
```

and dataframe 3

```
+----------+----------+--------------------+------------+
|    V1    | cluster  |    position.x      | position.y |
+----------+----------+--------------------+------------+
| <chr>    | <dbl>    |    <dbl>           |   <dbl>    |
| 1 conf9  |    7     | -0.0104            | 0.000920   |
| 2 conf9  |    9     |  -0.00426   0.0139 |            |
| 3 conf9  |   11     |   0.0249           | 0.0164     |
| 4 conf9  |   13     |  -0.0146           | 0.00242    |
| 5 conf9  |   15     |  -0.0176           | 0.00220    |
| 6 conf9  |   17     |  -0.0183           | 0.00620    |
+----------+----------+--------------------+------------+
```

I want to do row wise operation based on data1 values. For example I want to check that for each row in data1 if the values in columns `Particlei` and `particlej` are present in column `cluster` of data 2 and 3. After detecting if the values are present then perform some operations on rows in data2 and 3. For example for row number 1 in data1 I have 6 and 1829 so I want to select rows in column `cluster` in data2 and 3 which have 6 and 1829 and after selecting subtract column `position.x` of data3 from data2 for the two selected rows. similarly subtract column `position.y` of data3 from data2. do all these operations row wise. What I did till now

```
  for(i in row_number(data3)){
    y <- data1 %>% filter(any(data3[,1:2]==data2$cluster))
    if(any(data2$cluster==data3[,1:2])){
       while(any(data2$cluster==data3[,1])){
          delta_x = data2$position.x-data1$position.x
          delta_y = data2position.y-data1$position.y
  }
}
```

expected output

```
+---------------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
|             |            |                   |                   |                  |                  |           |                                                 |          |           |
|    V1       |     cluster| position.x_data3  | position.y_data3  | position.x_data2 | position.y_data2 | delta.x   | delta.y                                         | particlei | particlej |
| +---------+ |            |                   |                   |                  |                  |           |                                                 |           |           |
|  <chr>      | <dbl>      |  <dbl>            |   <dbl>           | <dbl>            | <dbl>            |  <dbl>    | <dbl>                                           |           |           |
|  1 conf9,10    | 6          | -0.0104           | 0.000920          | 0.000659         |  0.00932         | -0.011059 | -0.0084                                         | 6         | 1829     |
|  2 conf9,10    | 1829       |  -0.00426         | 0.0139            |  0.000659        | 0.000659         | 0.000659  | 0.000575                                        | 6         | 1829      |
|  3 conf9,10    |  7        |   0.0249          |  0.0164           | ...              | ,...             | ...       | some values subtracted between position columns | 7         | 13928     |
|  4 conf9,10    | 13928      |  -0.0146          |  0.00242          |  some values     | some values      | ...       | ...                                             | 7         | 13928     |
+---------------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Can you please include your expected output given this sample data?

Comment: It would also help if your sample data matched across the board. For instance, none of `data1$Particlej` exist anywhere in the other frames.

Comment: no its doesn't. it's only in data1. I have added the expected output

Comment: *"if the values in columns `Particlei` and `particlej` are present in column cluster of data 2 and 3"* says that you expect values in `Particlej` to be found in your other frames. I suggest that either _that_ statement can be better worded or your sample data needs to be revised.

Comment: yeah may be i need to re word it. I have edited expected output You can have a look at it. values in data2 and 3 `cluster` are from 1 to 20000 but values in `particlei` and `particle` can have missing values between 1 to 20000 so we can't expect every value of `cluster` to be present in data3.